# How to make a column increment by one each time when a condition is met

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a "W" column that I want to increase by one every time the "Res" column in the same row is reswin.

I can't figure how to make it increment based on the W value of the row before it. I was using python and the code I tried was this

```
c.execute("UPDATE profiletable SET W = W+1 WHERE Res = ?", (reswin,))
```

This adds 1 to whatever the first W value is already and doesn't update each row incrementally based on the previous row

Edit:
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZn3O.png)

Edit2:
I mean in order of rowid.

Comment: Please add sample table data, for both before and after.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Without a column specifying the ordering of the rows, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Edited, I mean in order of rowid

Comment: What is your version of SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE profiletable
SET W = W + (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM profiletable p 
  WHERE p.Res = profiletable.Res AND p.rowid <= profiletable.rowid
)
WHERE Res = ?;
```

If, like your sample data, all values of `W` are initially `0` then you can remove `W +` from the code and assign only the result of the subquery to `W`.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ec9ccbc70da8ba269395c44f4f15602b).

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you can use the `UPDATE...FROM` syntax with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
UPDATE profiletable AS p1
SET W = p1.W + p2.rn
FROM (
  SELECT *, rowid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rowid) rn
  FROM profiletable
  WHERE Res = ?
) p2
WHERE p2.rowid = p1.rowid;
```